# Frustration with superuser.com user interface

Tags: discussion

Can someone please migrate this question to "meta" for me?  I'm unable to post there while I wait for OpenID to fix my password problems.  Thanks.

I'm having problems with superuser.com's interface -- when I provide an answer to a question, sometimes the buttons get locked and then I find out that the question was migrated.  Usually I can go back and copy-and-paste my answer at whatever site it goes to, but on occasion my answer is lost and I have to re-type it.

This is very time-consuming, and makes it quite frustrating to use the system.  In addition, I find that I'm wasting a lot of time dealing with having to re-register on the other sites.

My suggestion is to not de-activate the "Submit answer" button but to just forward that along to the migrated site automatically, thus ensuring that answers that people put a lot of effort into don't get lost.

Comment: @Randolf If you want "immediate" migration, you can always flag your question for moderator attention and request migration.

Comment: You are an unregistered user. If you registered a lot of this would (hopefully) disappear.

Comment: Thanks BloodPhilia.  When I click on "flag," a pink oblong appears.  Clicking on it again makes it disappear.  I hope that worked, although I don't see any indication of this.

Comment: ChrisF:  I entered my name, eMail address, and an optional web site address in the form provided.

Comment: @Randolf As ChrisF said, you're unregistered. This means your Account only exists because it's stored in a cookie on your computer. If it gets lost, so is your account. Register your account by linking an OpenID to your account. You can do that by going to your [account's page](http://superuser.com/users/67387/randolf-richardson) and clicking "add openid" right next to "Unregistered User".

Comment: "Registered" means you have provided an OpenID. If you do that all your accounts on various sites will be linked, you'll be easily able to log in on any computer.

Comment: I agree with the having to register at the other sites thing.  It would be nice to have a share profile that covers all the sites and amalgamates all your reputation earned on all the sites into one global reputation number.

Comment: @MattJenkins Logging into http://stackexchange.com gives your global rep + profile - [like so](http://stackexchange.com/users/e0209733-7a27-4c72-9d82-6df973849773)

Comment: BloodPhilia and ChrisF:  It just happened again -- my comment got lost because the question got locked (thanks for migrating to "meta" though) and what I typed was lost.  Anyway, I have been trying to get my password from OpenID.org, and I just went through the "Claim password" routine again a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Randolf Just create a google account (Gmail) and use that as an openID...

Comment: @RandolfRichardson don't you have a GMail / Google/ facebook / Yahoo account ?

Comment: @Sathya Nope, can't log in - Google tells me `You are not authorized to perform this request.`

Comment: Sathya:  No, I don't have those accounts.  I manage my own eMail servers and I'm not interested in wasting time with free webmail interfaces.  I also have no interest in getting a FaceBook account because I have no need for it (plus it's a time-suck).  OpenID.org should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy + Pasting @[JeffAtwood'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81974/133693):

> edit: we *DO* provide feedback on
>   migrations to people answering via
>   topbar notification
>
> [image]
>
> The unsubmitted answer would still be
>   saved as a draft, since we auto-save
>   drafts for questions and answers every
>   45 seconds.
>
> However, I'm not 100% sure the draft
>   would *be visible* when you came back
>   to that answer. Normally it would be,
>   but since we suppress the answer
>   editing area on migrated / closed /
>   otherwise functionally unanswerable
>   questions.. might not be in that case.

Comment: That feedback bar hasn't shown up for me so far.  At any rate, sometimes the answer I typed gets lost so I've been trying to remember to copy-and-paste it before attempting to submit my answer.

Comment: Heheh, now when I go back to the main "Questions" page of SuperUser.com, I see the "your question was migrated" ribbon across the top, so at least it works there.  =)

Comment: Okay, I got a password from OpenID.org yesterday, but when I attempted to login it didn't work. I replied to that eMail and am still waiting a response from them.

In the meantime, I've just found my reputation count has been reset on the main part of this web site, but is still preserved okay here in meta. I'm not sure what's happened there, but I guess it has something to do with not having a registered account -- if that's the case, then I hope OpenID.org can get their system working properly soon.

Comment: Presumably you lost access to your previous cookie. There are different accounts -  http://superuser.com/users/67387/randolf-richardson ( old ) / http://superuser.com/users/71003/randolf-richardson ( new ). Merged the 2 users @Randolf

Comment: It seems to be there.  Thanks!  I feel like you folks really want me to be involved here, and I really do feel welcomed by all this immediate responsiveness and how seriously you take my concerns.  I'm impressed, and I hope to get this OpenID.org stuff sorted out soon.

Comment: @Sathya:  My cookie got lost again.  I'm at the point of just giving up on OpenID.org and will start to look at other options next.  I'm very disappointed with OpenID.org and I think you folks need to be aware that they're not a very good organization to partner with because they don't respond to questions from new users who are trying to sign up.  Is there an alternative to OpenID.org that provides better service that I could use?

Comment: @RandolfRichardson Stack Exchange is beta testing their own OpenID, you might want to try it http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91039/133693

Comment: @Sathya:  That one worked.  I have an account set up there now (the beta works!).  What can I do to link this to my past cookies which seem to have disappeared?

Comment: link to your new user URL @RandolfRichardson?

Comment: @Sathya:  Okay, I managed to get it working (hopefully these issues will all be resolved before the beta period comes to fruition), but I have a different account number.  I should be 67387, but somehow I ended up with 81651 on the main site.  If you can help to get this straightened out somehow, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Congrats @RandolfRichardson you finally have a registered account. You should have full access of this acount

Comment: @Sathya:  Thanks.  You also fixed up my account numbers and it seems to be working just fine now.  I do find this system really weird as far as how accounts are handled since the other sites I've used over the years always allow for a simple eMail-based registration.  Having the options for third-party trust is a nice idea, but also discouraging for people who don't have accounts on those other systems.  MyOpenID.org was a nightmare by the way -- they ignored eMails about their registration system not working, and I think regular end-users may blame StackExchange for third-party problems.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson you're welcome.. the team is aware of problems people are having with MyOpenID - hence this solution ( which you successfully beta tested ;) )

Comment: @Sathya:  Thanks again.  I'm curious, I recall that I used to have some silver badges as well, but they seem to have disappeared since getting registered.  It doesn't really matter to me that these disappeared, but I'm wondering if this is something the developers should know about?

Comment: @RandolfRichardson - hmm, interesting that. Might want to wait for a day or so - the badges are assigned as part of a scheduled job. Start a new separate question in here if you don't get them.

Comment: @Sathya:  That's no problem.  (One silver badge appeared just a few minutes ago, so perhaps there is a background updater process of some sort that's making things right.)