# Issues with OpenID.org - allow users register with their email?

Tags: support, user-accounts

User [Randolph Richardson](https://superuser.com/users/67387/randolf-richardson) is a contributing member of SU, but he is an unregistered user because he cannot get his OpenID.org account to work properly.  I have offered to merge his unregistered account with a new registered one, if he would like, but he is having a hard time working out his issue.

The conversation posted below is from [the comments of one of his answers](https://superuser.com/questions/257198/windows-7-x64-hard-freezing-again/257252#257252):

> if you register (free) and then email me, I can associate your unregistered account with your registered one, and then you can keep all of your rep and badges and posts, because the second you lose your browser cookie, you're locked out of your account... Just so you know... Welcome to SU! :)
>   – studiohack♦
>
> Thanks studiohack. I'm trying to get OpenID.org to work, but the password reset eMails lead me to a link that doesn't work properly. I've eMailed them a few times, and am still waiting for their response. I wish I could just register using my eMail address here without having to involve a third party. =(
>   – Randolf Richardson
>
> not exactly sure what you mean by all that, do you mean you have emailed the Super User team or what? You can register here by email, or via OpenID from a variety of sites... also, when replying to a comment, use the @ symbol so the user is notified, I was not notified that you left this comment, I just checked back...
>   – studiohack♦
>
> I sent an eMail back to OpenID.org (it's their issue because their system won't allow me to login, and their "reset password" method isn't working properly).
>   – Randolf Richardson
>
> ah makes more sense, thanks for clarifying. Keep me posted on how that works out and let me know if I can do anything to help!
>   – studiohack♦
>
> I had too many free accounts on various systems and was wasting too much time, so I eliminated almost all of them. I like what OpenID.org is doing (not wasting my time) so I kept it, but they changed their password system and required me to provide additional information to login (so I set that up) and I'm still unable to login to their system (my account worked before their upgrade). One thing you can do to help is try to suggest that SuperUser.com allow people to register with their eMail accounts (perhaps on "meta" where I can't post things as unregistered).
>   – Randolf Richardson
>
> @RandolfRichardson: [see this Meta.SU question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2196/issues-with-openid-org-allow-users-register-with-their-email)
>   – studiohack♦

What should he do?  Can he sign up via email registration alone?

Comment: See also comments on http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2159/frustration-with-superuser-com-user-interface

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83504/how-can-i-log-in-into-my-not-registered-so-account Might be of use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new account with whatever provider he wants, and merge the old and new accounts.

Be sure to merge in the new account direction so you retain the new openid provider.